# While loop displays column of data instead of rows

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to pull results from a `MySQL` database to appear in a grid like so:

**Result 1** - **Result 2** - **Result 3**

**Result 4** - **Result 5** - **Result 6**

etc. i.e. three results per row.

What is happening is this:

**Result 1**

**Result 2**

**Result 3**

**Result 4**

**Result 5**

**Result 6**

i.e. in a single column.

The HTML & `CSS` is set up for a grid, 3 X However many records.
But the `PHP` seems to ignore the grid layout and default to a single column.

My code so far is set out like this:

**HTML / PHP**

```
...
    <?php   
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('host', 'account', 'password', 'trialDB') or die('Error connecting to MySQL Server.');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM trialTBL ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {?>
        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="content">   
                <ul class="grid columns-3">
                    <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo $row['image'];?>" />
                        <h3><?php echo $row['title'];?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $row['description'];?></p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php   
    }   
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    ?>...
```

**CSS**

```
.mainContent{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3%;}

ul.grid {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0px;
    margin-left: -2.5%; /* should match li left margin */}

ul.grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 2.5% 2.5%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #dfdfdf;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;}

ul.grid li img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 10px;}

ul.grid li h3 {
    margin: 0 0 5px;}

ul.grid li p {
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #999;}

ul.grid.columns-3 li {
    width: 30.83%; /* this value + 2.5 should = 33% */}
```

**MySQL**

```
CREATE DATABASE trialDB;

USE trialDB;

CREATE TABLE trialTBL(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
image VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
description TEXT NOT NULL
);

DESCRIBE trialTBL;

INSERT INTO trialTBL (image, title, description)VALUES(
"images/temperature.png", 
"Temperature Conversion",
"How to convert from one temperature to another"
),
(
"images/temperature.png", 
"Temperature Conversion",
"How to convert from one temperature to another"
),
(
"images/temperature.png", 
"Temperature Conversion",
"How to convert from one temperature to another"
),
(
"images/temperature.png", 
"Temperature Conversion",
"How to convert from one temperature to another"
);

SELECT * FROM trialTBL\G
```

Comment: Yipee!!! It works, now have a grid layout (@Captain_a), thanks for all the help and quick replies ;-)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you are doing the loop to all your content including the `ul`, you have to loop just the `li`

something like this:

```
<div class="mainContent">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="grid columns-3">
      while
      <li>
        <img src="<?php echo $row['image'];?>" />
        <h3><?php echo $row['title'];?></h3>
        <p>
          <?php echo $row[ 'description'];?>
        </p>
      </li>
       end while }
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yip, as @Anant pointed out too, thanks for the further explanation, I was looking at it wrong myself.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
 ul.grid li {
    float: left;
 }
```

and if it doesn't fully works add also

```
width: 33%;
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help, never knew I could fix from the CSS side too.  It worked,  but  in the first row, the second and third records are pushed a few pixels slightly lower than the first.

Comment: Can you post an image of this issue?

Comment: @andy-r Can you put the source in jsfiddle (without the php only the rendered html and css)?

Comment: When I add more <li> elements it looks find. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1smcuw6L/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115622/discussion-between-shlomi-haver-and-andy-r).

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this :

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{?>
    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="content">   
            <ul class="grid columns-3">
                <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $row['image'];?>" />
                    <h3><?php echo $row['title'];?></h3>
                    <h3><?php echo $row['OTHER_COLUMN_NAME'];?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $row['description'];?></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php   
}
```

Comment: No, I'm afraid that doesn't work.  All records are displaying, it's the order/direction.  I want them 3 results to a row.  Then the next row of 3 results.  Currently I am getting one long column and no rows. I am not getting a 3 x 3 grid like appearance.

Comment: @AndyR you marked answer then unmarked. Again you marked and unmarked? any specific reason?

Comment: @AndyR 8 hours ago you post this question and got solution immediately but no response. This is really bad. I am going to delete my answer.